# How do I supply my own LoginForm to Pinax Auth?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication, pinax

My web app is built on top of Pinax. My problem has two parts.

## Part one

The default `LoginForm` does not provide a reCaptcha field. To check brute-force attempts I would like to include one, but for this I would need to supply my own sub-class of `LoginForm`.

From the source it seems like I can pass `form_class` as extra options to the included urls conf, but then this would set my version of form as the `form_class` for `signup` view too. That is unfortunate. Is there any other way?

## Part two

Second part of the problem is that I want to enhance the user experience. So, I would like to present the reCaptch field only when the users fails to authenticate for the third consecutive times. For this to work, I am considering keeping a failed attempt counter in the user session. The problem is how do get reference to session object from the `__init__()` of the form?

Is there anyway I can achieve this without modifying Pinax code?